# How to return the original log retention after purge kafka topics

Tags: linux, kafka

We have 3 kafka machines version - 0.10.0.2.6

We want to purge all data files from all kafka's topics ( purge completely all data )

The CLI for this action should be ( should be run from the zoo server )

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic1 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic2 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic3 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic4 --config retention.ms=1000
```

Since we Temporarily update the retention time on the topic to one second (1000 ms )

Then how to return the previous original retention!

Note - log.retention.hours = 168 ( from the ambari GUI ) and this is the original value

So how to return the original value (168 hours) back on all topics ? after purge all Topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the same command, but set the retention to 168 hours in milliseconds.